# Windows Phone 8 Longlistselector Image Cache

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a longlistselector in XAML:

```XAML
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListView}" Margin="0,140,0,0">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="210" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Height="110" Width="110" Grid.Column="0" Tap="Image_Tap" Source="{Binding profilePicURL}" Tag="{Binding username}" Margin="0,1"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" /> // blablabla
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" /> // blablabla
                <Image Grid.Column="3"/> // blablablabla
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

And the ListViewModel.cs

```C#
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _userid;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userid")]
        public string userid
        {
            get
            {
                return _userid;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _userid)
                {
                    _userid = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("userid");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _profilePicURL;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "profile_picture")]
        public string profilePicURL
        {
            get
            {
                return _profilePicURL;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _profilePicURL)
                {
                    _profilePicURL = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("profilePicURL");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _username;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
        public string username
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _username)
                {
                    _username = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("username");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I populate this list with 20 records from a database. And everything works fine but I don't like the fact that the app loads all the pics again when I refresh the list. Because when I refresh, the app loads again the most recent 20 records from internet and there are maybe 1 or 2 new entries on the top of this 20 slots list and all other pictures are already loaded. So how can I just "push" the older ones down and ONLY load the new records on the top. I don't want to download all the old Images again. How can I cache it? Of course the entries on the bottom will disappear when newer entries come on the top.

Answer (score 0):

[Save](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-images) the images in isolated storage folder. Load the images in the `list` from that folder.
Now, when new images are needed to be added, save them to the same folder and delete those that are not needed anymore.

This way the images will be cached even if the user closes the app and then reopens it, saving data for the user too.